# How to understand an undefined error in a function I'm trying to write

Tags: python

I'm a new engineer and I'm writing a simple phone book app in Python. It's pretty self explanatory, as it's a beginner project. When I was writing the function I forgot to tell it what to do if a entry that was being search wasn't found.

I have looked at several examples, and to the best of my growing knowledge base, coded what I thought was correct. I am getting an error and would like to understand it.

Also, optimization is key, so one of my objectives is to learn to code for optimization the first time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/corcoding/Desktop/projects/phonebook-project/phonebook.py", line 20, in <module>
    print("phone number of" ,name1, "is", d1==[name])
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Code:

```
def menu():
    print("-------Lil Black Book--------")
    print("[1] Look up an entry")
    print("[2] Set an entry")
    print("[3] delete an entry")
    print("[4] List all entries")
    print("[5] Quit")
    print("what would you like to do (1-5)?")

menu()

   
d1 = {}
while True:
    n=int(input("enter number [1-5]:-"))
    if n ==2:
        name=input("enter name:-")
        phono=(input("enter phone number:-"))
        d1[name]=phono
    elif n==1:
        name1=input("enter name to SEARCH for phone number in the phone book")
        print("phone number of" ,name1, "is", d1[name])
    if name1 != d1[name]:
        print("entry not found")    
    if n== 3:
        name1=input("enter name to delete:-")
        d1.pop(name)
    elif n==5:  
        break
```

Comment: Look at your flow and when you do or do not define `name` and `name1`. What would `name` be if you don't trigger your first `if` condition?

Comment: thank both of you for your responses.  to answer the question that was asked. I defined d1[name]=phono is that the correct answer to your question @mkrieger1?    @G.Anderson i'm still figuring through your comment thank you for the direction, im trying out some other things based upon both comments, thanks you two!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved up the validation and changed the code.

```
def menu():
    print("-------Lil Black Book--------")
    print("[1] Look up an entry")
    print("[2] Set an entry")
    print("[3] delete an entry")
    print("[4] List all entries")
    print("[5] Quit")
    print("what would you like to do (1-5)?")


menu()

d1 = {}
while True:
    n = int(input("enter number [1-5]:-"))
    if n == 2:
        name = input("enter name:-")
        phono = (input("enter phone number:-"))
        d1[name] = phono
    elif n == 1:
        name1 = input(
            "enter name to SEARCH for phone number in the phone book")
        if name1 != d1.get(name1,None): # Validate name exist
            print("entry not found")
        else:
            print("phone number of", name1, "is", d1[name])
    if n == 3:
        name1 = input("enter name to delete:-")
        d1.pop(name)
    elif n == 5:
        break
```

Test run.

```
[1] Look up an entry
[2] Set an entry
[3] delete an entry
[4] List all entries
[5] Quit
what would you like to do (1-5)?
enter number [1-5]:-1
enter name to SEARCH for phone number in the phone bookDoe
entry not found
enter number [1-5]:-
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code may accomplish what you are looking for:

```
d1 = {}
while True:
    n = int(input("enter number [1-5]:-"))
    if n == 1:
      name1 = input("enter name to SEARCH for phone number in the phone book")
      if not(name1 in d1.keys()):
        name1 = input("please enter someone who is already in your book")
      else:
        print("phone number of" ,name1, "is", d1[name1]) 
    elif n == 2:
        name = input("enter name:-")
        phono = (input("enter phone number:-"))
        d1[name]=phono
    elif n == 3:
        name1 = input("enter name to delete:-")
        d1.pop(name)
    elif n == 4:
        print(d1)
    elif n == 5:  
        break
```

First off, I ordered the `if` statements by `n` so it is easier to read.

Note that indenting does matter in Python! Whatever you want to run inside of an `if` statement must be indented inside of it.

The main issue is when `n = 1`. This is because we do not know if `name1` exists inside of `d1`. Therefore, we must first check if `name1` exists inside of `d1` before calling `d1[name1]`.

Comment: Use `elif` for mutually exclusive conditions. And `break` is not indented properly.

Comment: "indexing" should be "indenting"

Comment: The ```break``` didn't copy and paste over correctly, thanks. Also since they are mutually exclusive doesn't that mean that elif is uneccesary?

Comment: The point is to not waste time checking all the other conditions once you've found the only possible match. And even if you don't care about performance, it makes it clear to readers that they're exclusive

Comment: Also helps with readability

Comment: True, I edited it.